# Show which files changed in incoming git commits

Tags: git, logging

I'd like to see which files were touched after having fetched new commits. I want it in the same way that you'd see the files after a merge: list of files, with "x times" + (for lines inserted) and "y times" - (for lines deleted).

I've tried:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h %d %s %an %ar' --date=short --stat HEAD..origin
```

but:

1. it shows me commits one by one -- while I want to see the whole set of touched files as if there was only one big commit
2. it does not stop at old commits I already had on my machine.

So, the goal here is really to see at a glance: if I merge all the new commits, which files are changed by the incoming commits?

Comment: `git diff --stat HEAD origin`? Although I suspect your `HEAD` and `origin` refs aren't really what you want - probably more like `master` and `origin/master` or something...

Comment: Of course: using diff, not log!

Comment: Though, while this does work perfectly for the master branch, it does not for the current branch. How can I adapt the command so that it does always work on the current branch -- without changing the syntax of the command (my goal is to have a static alias I can just type)?  Thanks.

Comment: Answer directly in the "Answer" space so that I can flag your answer as correct, when you'll provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to get the type of report you are looking for is to use `git diff`. For example:

```
git diff --stat master origin/master
```

If your local branches and their upstream counterparts always follow the same pattern (e.g. `foo` and `origin/foo`), then writing a small shell function into an alias should work - something like this in your `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
upstreamdiff = "!f(){ git diff --stat ${1} origin/${1} }; f"
```

If you have remotes that aren't named `origin`, or if you're not in the habit of using matching branch names, it becomes more complex, and you might need a full-on shell script to take a branch, find it's upstream partner, and then run the appropriate `git diff` command.

EDIT: to incorporate automatic branch determination:

```
alias
upstreamdiff = "!f() { b=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD); git diff --stat ${b} origin/${b} }; f"
```

Comment: Instead of having to type the branch name (and, yes, I assume they're the same on both sides), is it possible to derive the current branch name, so that just typing "git upstreamdiff" would do the right thing in all branches?

Comment: You could use `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` for that, as long as you know you are on a branch. If you're ever in a detached head state, though, that won't work...

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks for the precision about detached state!

Answer (score 1):

You ask

> see which files were touched after having fetched

If you fetch multiple times without doing a `merge` or a `rebase`, then diffing from `merge-base` of your branch to your upstream will give you the sum of all of those fetches, and not just the most recent recent fetch.  I find it useful to have both -  I alias one of them to `unmerged` and the other to `whatfetched`.

Also, git provides builtin functionality to identify your upstream that will work even if the branch you are tracking doesn't have the same name, this is via the special ref `@{u}`.

So for what you would want, you would need to check

```
git rev-parse @{u}
```

That will tell you whether or not your branch has an upstream.

To get the name of your upstream you could use

```
 git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u}
```

This will print our `origin/$BRANCH`, and will work even if you branch is tracking a branch with a different name.  Assign that to $UPSTREAM

So see just the most recent fetch (`whatfetched`), you would use the reflog to show only the changes between where upstream is currently pointing and where it was pointing previously.

```
git diff --stat $(UPSTREAM) ^$(UPSTREAM)@{1}
```

If you wanted to see what precisely you were looking at here you could use something like

```
git reflog ${UPSTREAM}@{now} -2
```

To see the sum of all changes you haven't incorporated (`unmerged`), you would want to diff from the `merge-base` of your branch and the upstream to the upstream with

```
git diff --stat HEAD...$(UPSTREAM)
```